# How can i open a new blank windows with tinymce?

Tags: javascript, tinymce, rte, tinymce-3

I found this code:

```
ed.windowManager.open({
                    file: url + '/youtube.htm',
                    width: 320 + parseInt(ed.getLang('example.delta_width', 0)),
                    height: 120 + parseInt(ed.getLang('example.delta_height', 0)),
                    inline: 1
}
```

but i don't know how to use it to open a blank new window, could someone help me?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may use this (no tinymce solution)

```
window.open (url + '/youtube.htm', "mywindow","resizable=1,inline=1,width="+320 + parseInt(ed.getLang('example.delta_width', 0))+"height="+120 + parseInt(ed.getLang('example.delta_height', 0)) );
```

Here is a link to a tutorial on how to use all possible options: http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml

Here is some code that will work from tinymce and is easily able to communicate with the tinymce editor instance:

```
ed.windowManager.open({
  url: tinymce.baseURL + '/plugins/myplugin/test.html', // empty?
  width: 600 + parseInt(ed.getLang('example.delta_width', 0)),
  height: 200 + parseInt(ed.getLang('example.delta_height', 0)),
  inline: true
}, {
  own_param: 'my_param',
  own_param2: 'my_param2'
});
```